# Swift add Icon & Text to Swipe Cell Action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to add icon to Swipe Action but i don't find any solution. Someone says that " It's not possible with 'trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt' ". Is that true or Is there any solution ? Thank you for replies.

[image]

Comment: hi ali can you show me some images so i can get exact idea what u want..

Answer (score 5):

Try Like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                       trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
      let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
                // Your Call Here
                success(true)
      })
      deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "Trash")
      deleteAction.backgroundColor = COLOR_ORANGE

      return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

Comment: It works but when i add the icon , the text is disappeared. Is it avaliable add with same time ?

Comment: you can add icon with text

Comment: How? . Title does not response.

Comment: icon means png image that contains the text

Comment: How i change the texts with localization ?

Comment: Its the bug in UIContextualAction. It does not show both image and title at the same time unless the table view cell height is 91 points. If you specify image that contains icon and text make sure cell is having proper height.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you can add your custom logic that will help you.This will work for ios 11.

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIContextualAction *delete = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleDestructive
                                                                         title:@"DELETE"
                                                                       handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
                                                                           NSLog(@"index path of delete: %@", indexPath);
                                                                           completionHandler(YES);
                                                                       }];

    UIContextualAction *rename = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleNormal
                                                                         title:@"RENAME"
                                                                       handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
                                                                           NSLog(@"index path of rename: %@", indexPath);
                                                                           completionHandler(YES);
                                                                       }];

    UISwipeActionsConfiguration *swipeActionConfig = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[rename, delete]];
    swipeActionConfig.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = NO;

    return swipeActionConfig;
}
```

I hope this will help you

Thanks